# How does this implementation of operator[] function work?

Tags: c++, vector, 3d, game-engine

I am working through a book (Foundations Of Game Engine Development By Eric Lengyel) and the book is writing out some vector operations in c++, here is the snippet:

```
struct Vector3D
{
    float x, y, z;

    Vector3D() = default;

    Vector3D(float a, float b, float c)
    {
        x = a;
        y = b;
        z = c;
    }

    float& operator [](int i)
    {
        return((&x)[i]);
    }
};
```

im particularly concerned with this piece:

```
float& operator [](int i)
{
    return((&x)[i]);
}
```

Now I would expect this code to return x, no matter what index is entered. However the corresponding variable (x, y, or z) is output depending on the input. Why is this? Thanks for the help.

Comment: That's abusing [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) (dereferencing a pointer out of bounds) by knowing the implementation-specific layout of how the compiler puts members in the objects. If your book recommends something like that, then you should throw it away!

Comment: Following what @Someprogrammerdude said, I'd like to add that it's one of the worst kinds of undefined behavior, undefined behavior that will work 99.9% of the time (because very few compilers are going to rearrange or place padding between these floats). If/when it does crash, it will be very difficult to track down.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the book doesn't particularly recommend it, but suggests that this is a simple c++ representation of a 3d Vector. Would it be better to use a switch with case 0: return &x, case 1: return &y, etc?

Comment: @JoeGuida, it would be easier to just define a 3-element array, or better yet use `std::array<float, 3>`

Comment: @AndyG, thanks, accessing the elements directly is fine with me eg: v.x, v.y, v.z. I was just wondering how that operator worked. He does a similar one here Vector3D& operator *= (float s)
 {
  x *= s;
  y *= s;
  z *= s;

  return (*this);
 }

Answer (score 3):

For a few moments, let's ignore the foul smell of the way the function has been implemented.

The question is, how does it ever work?

If you look at the member variables of an object of the class, when there is no padding between members, they are laid out in memory as:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|  x  |  y  |  z  |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

With such a layout, the object appears as though it is an array of `float`s.

If you use:

```
float* ptr = &x;
```

`ptr` points to the first element of such an array.

`ptr[0]` evaluates to the first element of the array, which is the same as `x`.
`ptr[1]` evaluates to the second element of the array, which is the same as  `y`.
`ptr[2]` evaluates to the third element of the array, which is the same as  `z`.

That's why

```
return((&x)[i]);
```

works most of the time, even though such code is cause for undefined behavior per the standard.

Comment: **If** you know what your compiler does, either because it documents it or because you test **meticulously**, you can do this. Just don't forget to repeat the tests every time you change compilers or compiler options.